# Scroll animation in plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a scroll animation section when visitors click on the anchor. As you might notice the variable "id" will show #1, this will match the id value of the section itself. How could I add the scroll animation to this javascript?

```js
var section = document.getElementsByTagName("section"),
  nav = document.getElementById("nav-bar"),
  navHeight = nav.offsetHeight,
  navAnchor = nav.querySelectorAll("li a");

for (var i = 0; i < navAnchor.length; i++) {
  var element = navAnchor[i];

  element.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var el = this,
      id = el.getAttribute("href");

    function scrollTo(element, to, duration) {
      var element = element,
        to = section + id;
      console.log(id);
      if (duration <= 0) {
        return;
      }
      var difference = to - element.scrollTop;
      var perTick = difference / duration * 10;
      consolelo

      setTimeout(function() {
        element.scrollTop = element.scrollTop + perTick;
        if (element.scrollTop === to) return;
        scrollTo(element, to, duration - 10);

      }, 500);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-block" id="nav-bar">
  <ul class="navbar-unordered-list">
    <li class="link">
      <a href="#1" class="active">Profile</a>
    </li>

    <li class="link">
      <a href="#2" class="scroll">Personal Project</a>
    </li>

    <li class="link">
      <a href="#3" class="scroll">Skills</a>
    </li>

    <li class="link">
      <a href="#4" class="scroll">CSS Drawings</a>
    </li>

    <li class="link">
      <a href="#5" class="scroll">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<section class="sections section1" id="1">
  1
</section>

<section class="sections section2" id="2">
  2
</section>

<section class="sections section3" id="3">
  3
</section>

<section class="sections section4" id="4">
  4
</section>

<section class="sections section5" id="5">
  5
</section>
```

Comment: *"There are tons of examples of scroll animations in jQuery, but not much of JavaScript."* The jQuery ones **are** in JavaScript. They're just using jQuery instead of using the DOM directly.

Comment: I meant vanilla JavaScript

Comment: You need to preventDefault

Comment: It's still vanilla JavaScript. Using a library doesn't change the *language* you're working with. The distinction is between "using jQuery" and "using the DOM directly," it has nothing whatsoever to do with the language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you see it move at all is that you haven't prevented the default action of following the link, which takes you to the anchor the link references. :-)

Separately from that, the `scrollTo` function shouldn't be inside the event handler.

Assuming you want to adjust the main scrollbar, I wouldn't use `setInterval`, I'd use `requestAnimationFrame`, see comments:

```js
var section = document.getElementsByTagName("section"),
  nav = document.getElementById("nav-bar"),
  navHeight = nav.offsetHeight,
  navAnchor = nav.querySelectorAll("li a"),
  animate = findAnimationElement();

for (var i = 0; i < navAnchor.length; i++) {
  var element = navAnchor[i];

  element.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var el = this,
      id = el.getAttribute("href");

    e.preventDefault(); // <=== Don't follow the link
    scrollTo(document.getElementById(id.substring(1)), 300);
    // Skip the "#" on "#1" -----------^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  });
}

function findAnimationElement() {
  // Webkit browsers animate `body`, others animate `html` (the document element)
  var bodyCurrent = document.body.scrollTop;
  var docElCurrent = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop = 10;
  var animate;
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 0) {
    animate = document.body;
    document.body.scrollTop = bodyCurrent;
  } else {
    animate = document.documentElement;
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = docElCurrent;
  }
  return animate;
}

function scrollTo(to, duration) {
  // When should we finish?
  var finishAt = Date.now() + duration;
  
  // Start
  requestAnimationFrame(tick);

  function tick() {
    // How many frames left? (60fps = 16.6ms per frame)
    var framesLeft = (finishAt - Date.now()) / 16.6;
    
    // How far do we have to go?
    var distance = to.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    if (distance <= 0) {
      // Done (this shouldn't happen, belt & braces)
      return;
    }
    
    // Adjust by one frame's worth
    if (framesLeft <= 1) {
      // Last call
      animate.scrollTop += distance;
    } else {
      // Not the last, adjust and schedule next
      animate.scrollTop += Math.max(1, distance / framesLeft);
      requestAnimationFrame(tick);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-block" id="nav-bar">
  <ul class="navbar-unordered-list">
    <li class="link">
      <a href="#1" class="active">Profile</a>
    </li>

    <li class="link">
      <a href="#2">Personal Project</a>
    </li>

    <li class="link">
      <a href="#3">Skills</a>
    </li>

    <li class="link">
      <a href="#4">CSS Drawings</a>
    </li>

    <li class="link">
      <a href="#5">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<section class="sections section1" id="1">
  1
</section>

<section class="sections section2" id="2">
  2
</section>

<section class="sections section3" id="3">
  3
</section>

<section class="sections section4" id="4">
  4
</section>

<section class="sections section5" id="5">
  5
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: One more thing, I have set the navbar with position: fixed; This function will only scroll down, but not up.....

Comment: @Front-endDeveloper: That may be as simple as changing the `if (distance <= 0)` check to `if (distance == 0)`. :-)

Comment: @Front-endDeveloper To scroll back up, besides the mentioned `if (distance == 0)`, I had to remove the `Math.max();` resulting in `animate.scrollTop +=  distance / framesLeft;`

Answer (score 0):

try to use this

```
function animate(elem, style, unit, from, to, time, prop) {
    if (!elem) {
        return;
    }
    var start = new Date().getTime(),
        timer = setInterval(function () {
            var step = Math.min(1, (new Date().getTime() - start) / time);
            if (prop) {
                elem[style] = (from + step * (to - from))+unit;
            } else {
                elem.style[style] = (from + step * (to - from))+unit;
            }
            if (step === 1) {
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
        }, 25);
    if (prop) {
          elem[style] = from+unit;
    } else {
          elem.style[style] = from+unit;
    }
}

window.onload = function () {
    var target = document.getElementById("div5");
    animate(document.scrollingElement || document.documentElement, "scrollTop", "", 0, target.offsetTop, 2000, true);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I see what you're getting at...

The only way to move the window with JS (Pure) is to create a progressive frame animation. You can do that as follows...

```
function animate() {
var nave = document.getElementById("navAnchor"); 
var id = setInterval(frame, 40);
var top = nave.offfset.top;
  function frame() {
    if (pos == 100) {
        clearInterval(id);
    } else {
        pos++; 
        nave.style.top = pos + 'px';
    }
  }
}
```

If you are open, you're life might be simplified if you allowed for Jquery which has animation controls built in.

```
$("nav").click(function() {
    $("#navAnchor").animate({
        top: 200;
    });
};
```

Another, less elegant, option is to shift the entire body  using a CSS animation and JS button.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that is much more readible. Enjoy!

```js
"use strict";

(function() {

  // Scroll function
  const scrollTo = (element, to, duration) => {
    if (duration <= 0) {
     return;
    }
    const difference = to - element.scrollTop;
    const perTick = difference / duration * 10;
    
    setTimeout(() => {
  element.scrollTop = element.scrollTop + perTick;
  if (element.scrollTop === to) {
   return;
  }
  scrollTo(element, to, duration - 10);
    }, 1);
  }
  
// Top Navigation
// Save DOM elements that can be scrolled to
// let targetElements = {};

let targetElements = {};

(function() {
 var section = document.getElementsByTagName("section");
 targetElements = section; 
})();

// Select links with scroll action
const scrollElements = document.getElementsByClassName('scroll');

// Add event listeners to navigation links with scroll action
Array.prototype.forEach.call(scrollElements, scrollElement => {
 scrollElement.addEventListener('click', event => {
    event.preventDefault(); // avoid jumping

    const targetElement = targetElements[(scrollElement.getAttribute('href').slice(1))];
    scrollTo(document.body, targetElement.offsetTop, 1000);
 });
});
})();
```

Answer (score -4):

You can use the jQuery.
With just a few lines of code!
First, put the following link inside the head:

````
    ```
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    ```
````

Then:

````
    ```
    <script>            
    $('#btn').click(function () {
            $('body, html').animate({
                'scrollTop': 100 // <--- How far from the top of the screen?100?
            }, 1000);// <---time = 1s
        });
    </script>
    ```
````